# Cambiar valor a archivo App.config

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando cambiar el valor del archivo App.config y no me guarda nada, no me salta ningún error al guardar, y cuando vuelve a ejecutar el programa sigue con el mismo valor.

```
var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var settings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;

Console.WriteLine(settings["id_shops"].Value = "50");

configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configFile.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
```

Comment: no estarás cambiando el archivo app.config que se te genera en bin/Debug? Si es así es normal que no te guarde los cambios, al compilar sobreescribe ese por el fichero original. Tienes que realizar los cambios en el que está en la raiz de tu proyecto

Comment: Exacto era por eso... Gracias! @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Añade ese comentario como una respuesta para que JoseYeste pueda marcarla como respuesta y dejar la pregunta cerrada.

Comment: Ya está la respuesta publicada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que el fichero que estás modificando es el de la carpeta bin/Debug.
Es normal que no te guarde los cambios porque al compilar, sustituye este fichero por el original y lo sobreescribe.

Para solucionar esto, sólo tienes que realizar los cambios en el fichero original, situado en la raíz del proyecto y al compilar verás que te ha guardado los cambios.